# Javascript Popup Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using this code code to set the cookie on my website so that the user will not see the popup for an amount of time that is set.

However when I don't close the popup the cookie doesn't save, I.e if the user clicks a link on the popup they will again receive the popup when visiting this page.

Any solutions would be much appreciated.

```
/* function use to set the cookie for next visualization time */
function itro_set_cookie(c_name,value,exhours) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + (exhours * 3600 * 1000));
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exhours==null) ? "" : ";    expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + "; path=/";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your function itro_set_cookie is accessible in popup or the layout designed for popup.